# Send Grid mail functionality not working in .net Framweork 4

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, sendgrid

I am using following code in .Net Framework 4.0. The sendgrid package version is 6.1.0 However when I build the project, build fails but there are no errors. When I run the same code in .Net 4.5.1 it works. Please suggest as I have to use .Net 4.0 only

```
SendGridMessage myMessage = new SendGrid.SendGridMessage();
myMessage.AddTo("abcd@xyz.com");

myMessage.From = new MailAddress("qwe@xyz.com", "Update");
myMessage.Subject = "New Update";
myMessage.Text = "Processed sucessfully";

var transportWeb = new Web("<API Key>");
transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage).Wait();
```

Comment: See my update for an answer to your question

Comment: Under .Net framework 4.0 version of SendGrid, are you able to create a new instance of Web using the API Key? I only see the option to create it using NetworkCredential.

Answer (score 3):

**Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3** is a dependency of **SendGrid 6.1.0** and it requires `.NET 4.5`

Use a lower version of SendGrid. For example [SendGrid 5.1.0](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid.Net40)

Note: Ofcourse the best solution is to get rid of your dependency of .NET 4.0. Is there really any good reason for not updating to a newer version?

Comment: I am using the Send Grid API key instead of username, password approach. This approach was working with sendgrid 6.1.0 in .Net 4.5.1, However, we need to use sendgrid in 4.0